# Clang Comparison Bug with negative values in strongly typed enum?

Tags: c++11, enums, clang

I recently dealt with code using a strongly typed enum that contained negative values.
When comparing the values of the enum, I got weird results when compiling the code with Clang (3.3) while Gcc works just fine.

Here is a small example with an assert that fails.

```
enum class T: int { A = -1, B = 1 };

int main() {
    T a = T::A, b = T::B;
    assert(a < b);
}
```

Is this an actual bug? Or does clang behave correctly and gcc just offers some kind of legacy support?

Comment: I don't think it should compile.

Comment: Martinho, if you add #include <cassert> the code compiles and the mentioned problem occurs when compiling with clang++ and c++11 enabled.

Comment: Assertion doesn't fail on clang++3.4 trunk 193040. @R.MartinhoFernandes I think the relational operators *can* be applied to scoped enums; I cannot find anything in it that forbids it. (Yes, integral promotion is a no-op, but still [expr.rel]/5 says "If both operands (after conversions) are of arithmetic or enumeration type, each of the operators shall yield
`true` if the specified relationship is true and `false` if it is false.")

Comment: There have been [problems with signedness of enumerators](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4515) in the past for clang, but I cannot find a bug report that matches this example.

Comment: 7.2/9 says it explicitly, scoped enums can't be implicitly converted to integers.

Comment: @DanielKO So? [expr.rel]/5 says (as far as I understand it) that values of enumeration type can be compared. `==` works as well for scoped enums.

Answer (score 0):

It should be more intuitive that the following is *well-formed*:

```
T a = T::A;
assert(a == T::A);
```

But the equality operators (`==`, `!=`) have the same restrictions as the relational operators (`<`, `<=`, ..) [expr.eq]/1:

> The `==` (equal to) and the `!=` (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result.

So if equality between values of a scoped enumeration type is well-defined, so should `<` be.

---

[expr.rel]/1

> The operands shall have arithmetic, enumeration, or pointer type, or type `std::nullptr_t`.

Of course, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on operands of arithmetic or enumeration type [expr.rel]/2, where the conversion is the identity conversion for scoped enumerations (no integral promotion, see [expr]/10 first bullet). However, [expr.rel]/5 explicitly states:

> If both operands (**after conversions**) are of arithmetic or enumeration type, each of the operators shall yield
>   `true` if the specified relationship is true and `false` if it is false.

(emphasis mine)

Therefore, `T::A < T::B` should be well-formed *and* yield `true`.

---

As I already wrote in a comment, the assertion doesn't fail on clang++3.4 trunk 193040. I therefore assume it's a bug that has been fixed, even though I couldn't find a corresponding bug report.